# casting Base* to the correct derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Assume a `std::vector<Base*>`, and a set of classes `Derived1`,..., `DerivedN`.

What is the correct/best architecture to decide on runtime to which of the `Derived*` classes I should `dynamic_cast` to?

Example:
I have the following classes: `Cat`,`Dog`,`Horse`,etc. They all have a Base class `Animal`.
I have a function to create an instance(s) of each of the derived classes, and I want to save the pointers somewhere, e.g. Bases* `ptrs2derivedclesses`.

Is there's a better way to save all the derived classes instances?

Comment: what does the vector have to with that decision?

Comment: The best architecture would be not to cast anything.

Comment: @Thomas the vector has nothing to do with it, it is just a container to state that the number of elements changes dynamically

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: how can I hold M objects of N different classes (that all have one common base class)

Comment: why do you need to cast? like @Yksisarvinen said, it would be ideal if the Base interface suffices.

Comment: I usually put an enum and a private enum value into the base class and let the derived class pass the correct enum value down to differentiate between classes.

Comment: @RickPat this is usual wrong approach in OOP

Comment: @Slava Ok, i know that you should avoid downcasting objects, others have already said so. but is there a better way to differentiate between classes, or is there something wrong about it?

Comment: If you need to differentaiate them, why store them as base object? Have a vector of `Dog`s, vector of `Cat`s and vector of `Horse`s. We're trying to tell you that you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and it will most likely be better solved by other means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the correct/best architecture to decide on runtime to which of the Derived* classes I should dynamic_cast to?

Correct/best approach is to design proper interface of the base class using (pure) virtual functions. Dynamic/static cast is usable sometimes in special cases but in general it is a sign of a bad design.